# Huge amount of plaintext data for parsing experiment

Tags: dataset, plaintext

I am developing a parser in ruby which parses some nonuniform text data. Can anybody tell me, where I can get a good number of plaintext data for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's you'll get a list of many:

http://www.quora.com/Data/Where-can-I-get-large-datasets-open-to-the-public

And my fav is:

http://ftp.sunet.se/mirror/archive/ftp.sunet.se/pub/tv+movies/imdb/

Comment: As long as amazon us-east-1d is up :)

Answer (score 5):

You could scrape [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/) (or just run a bunch of it through `lynx -dump`). That would also give you a vast source of non-English text as well. [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/) would be another good source of large amounts of plain text.

Comment: @Phrogz: I used to be a Gutenberg addict back in my "Palm Pilot and commuting on the bus" days.

Comment: Project Gutenberg as a very strict bot policy, they allow no more than 100 visits from the same ip address in a day.

Comment: @kyle k  That's ok. They have a torrent: http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:The_CD_and_DVD_Project